# How to conformally transform Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, conformal-field-theory

I have learnt that a conformal transformation in general relativity is where spacetime metrics can be mathematically cast as some function multiplied by the Minkowski null co-ordinate line element;
$$d\tilde{s}^2 = C(r) dudv \tag*{(The tilde meaning non-flat spacetime)}$$

Which allow Minkowski space and all its nice features to be effectively recovered if a specific co-ordinate choice is made.

The Schwarzschild metric has the conformal factor:
$$C(r) = \big( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \big)$$

However, when I expand the $dudv$ in to $dt^2 - dr^2$, I do not recover the Schwarzschild metric but;
$$ds^2 = \big( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \big)dt^2 - \big( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \big)dr^2$$

From literature, I know the factor of $dr^2$ should be the reciprocal of $\big( 1 - \frac{2M}{r} \big)$.

I think my understanding is in a bad way, any insight would be appreciated

Comment: $u$ and $v$ are NOT related to $t$ and $r$ the way you used it. The relationship is more complicated and finding this is part of the work that needs to be done.

Comment: So, in the question, should $ds$ be the Minkowski line element and the $u$, $v$ be the null co-ordinates of the spacetime of interest? (I had thought it was the other way around) Thanks

Comment: both of your line elements should be $ds^2$ and they both denote the Schwarzschild solution. The only thing is that the coordinates $u$ and $v$ are NOT defined by $u=t-r$, $v=t+r$. This relationship only holds for the flat solution. You will have to find the correct relationship in this case.